# Java program doesn't response when encrypting the large files is running

Tags: java, user-interface, encryption, out-of-memory

I am working on an Encryption/Decryption java program with AES CBC mode, and I used `cipher.update()` with `cipher.doFinal()` to be to deal with large files and avoid `outOfMemoryException`.
Now, when encrypting/decrypting large files (like 2 GB), in background everything is working perfectly (I can see in the Intellij run) but the GUI of my program doesn't respond when this processing is running and till the encryption/decryption is done. 
Moreover, there is no errors in run, so what could be the issue?

Comment: What kind of GUI is it? Are you running CPU-heavy code on the UI thread?

Comment: I am not sure that I got the question but it is the only way to encrypt the large files is by using update() without getting outOfMemory exception, and my Jar UI is simple, I doesn't do any updates on it during the process but only when it is done.

Comment: You can't use only one thread for both doing the work and updating your UI. You will need to use two threads at a minimum.

Comment: GUI frameworks: **swing**: JFrame, **OpenFX**: .fxml or javaFX launch, old **awt**: Frame/Window, **none**: just java `main` method. As every GUI has its own processing of events, some info would be usefull.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're using the UI thread for computing. Use a background thread.

If your UI is swing, `SwingWorker` could be used.

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably running the encryption on the UI thread which will lock the UI from responding until the encryption is complete. You should instead spawn a new thread and run the encryption within that so that your UI remains responsive.

Also be sure to atleast add a minimal amount of code to the question so that people can help you better here.

Comment: I agree Calvin but I was not sure which part could be the issue. Do you have any good way to implement more than UI thread?

Comment: Firstly could you elaborate your question by specifying which UI framework you are using and how exactly your are doing the encryption?